# Postgres import XML file with multiple elements to multiple tables

Tags: xml, database, postgresql

Does anyone have idea how do i import the following XML into separate tables.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <data>
  <customer>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>John</name>
  </customer>
  <customer>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>Smith</name>
  </customer>
   .
   .
   .
  <city>
   <name>London</name>
   <code>LO</code>
  </city>
  <city>
   <name>Paris</name>
   <code>PA</code>
  </city>
   .
   .
   .
 </data>
```

should be imported into customers and cities tables.

Comment: is this XML already presented in some database column? what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a FAQ; have you searched for prior questions that are similar?

Comment: @Dmitry Its raw file with millions of lines

Comment: @Craig Ringer I've searched but all examples are pretty simple